# Запись в БД даных из xml запроса

Tags: php, mysql, xml, post

Делаю скрипт для системы digiseller, есть сайт на котором уже есть определенная база пользователей, вот сам скрипт:

```
<?php
$data = $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;//Данные с xml-запроса
preg_match("|<email>(.*)</email>|sei", $data, $email);//Получаем почту
$mysqli = new mysqli(...);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Не удалось подключиться: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET group = 'USERS,VIP' WHERE email = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email[1]);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Но по какой то причине скрипт не работает, так же можно ли в этом случае использовать функцию 'xmlrpc_encode'.
Возможно причина в кавычках? `'USERS,VIP'`

Формат запроса:

```
<request>
<id>1976637</id>
<inv></inv>
<amount></amount>
<type_curr></type_curr>
<sign></sign>
<fio></fio>
<email></email>
<key></key>
</request>
```

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает скрипт?

Comment: Ошибки нет, просто ничего не происходит

Comment: @edvardpotter  покажите что попадает в $email (например, выввод var_dump) и содержимое $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA (в урезаном варианте)

Comment: @zenith Обновил вопрос.

Comment: а где же $email ? И по вопросу: проблема точно не в кавычках. 'USERS,VIP' это просто строка которая будет вставлена в поле group

Comment: @zenith `preg_match("|<email>(.*)</email>|sei", $data, $email);//Получаем почту` и вот заменяем `?` на `$stmt->bind_param("s", $email[1]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В программировании не существует такой задачи, как "Запись в БД даных из xml запроса". 
В программировании может существовать только две задачи:

1. "Чтение даных из xml запроса"
2. "Запись данных в БД"

И делать эти две задачи надо по отдельности. 
И если какая-то из задач не получается, то по ней и задавать свой вопрос.

Выяснить, работает ли код для решения той или иной задачи, можно способом, который называется "проверка результатов". Способ заключается в том, что по окончании выполнения программой задачи программист проверяет результат её выполнения. Сравнивая полученный результат с ожидаемым.

Для каждой задачи по отдельности

Comment: Я написал код для этих 2 задач, код не работает, я хочу узнать почему.